# Multiplicative inverse of the power series $e^x - c$ for $c \neq 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series, exponential-function

We know that the power series $f(x)= e^x -c \in \mathbb C[[x]]$ for $c \neq 1$, has a multiplicative inverse, since it's constant coefficient is non-zero. I was wondering whether the inverse is known in a closed form. Something like inverse of $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$, which is interesting as it generates the Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+1%2F%28e%5Ex-c%29) can find the inverse in terms of $c$.

The denominators of each term are easy to express in closed form.

The polynomials in the numerators seem to follow [Euler's triangle](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_numbers,_triangle_of#Euler.27s_triangle).